# JAXB - Extra Characters are added after the closing of the root tag

Tags: java, jaxb2

When I marshal Java objects into XML, some extra characters are added after the closing of the root tag.

Here is how I save the resulting java objects after unmarshaling from XML into a file:

```
public void saveStifBinConv(ConversionSet cs, String xmlfilename) {
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(xmlfilename);
        this.marshaller.marshal(cs, new StreamResult(os));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        log.fatal("IOException when marshalling STIF Bin Conversion XML file");
        throw new WmrFatalException(e);
    }
    finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                log.fatal("IOException when closing FileOutputStream");
                throw new WmrFatalException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The extra characters are padded after closing tag of the root tag.

The characters added are some of the characters from the XML. Example: `tractor-to-type><bin-code>239</bin-code><allowed>YES</allowed></extractor-to></extractor-mapping><extractor-mapping><e`

I use Spring OXM's `Jaxb2Marshaller` and JAXB 2.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Which characters are added? Also provide marshalling related code instead of populating of the model.

Comment: The characters added are some of the characters from the XML. Example: `tractor-to-type><bin-code>239</bin-code><allowed>YES</allowed></extractor-to></extractor-mapping><extractor-mapping><e`

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example for the extra characters you get. And the code above probably doesn't help. What's in `saveStifBinConv()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because I do 2 steps in saving the `XML`:

1. marshal the `XML` to a `FileOutputStream`, resulting in an `XML` file
2. then open a `FileInputStream` on the `XML` file in step 1 and write the `FileInputStream` to a `ServletOutputStream`

There must be a `buffer underflow` happening.

**Solution**

Marshal the `XML` directly to a `ServletOutputStream` (for web user to download the `XML` file).

```
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(pkg);
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal(cs, os);
```

where `os` is a `ServletOutputStream`.

```
    //return an application file instead of html page
    response.setContentType("text/xml");//"application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
        + xmlFilename);

    OutputStream out = null;
    out = response.getOutputStream();
```